# Unable to display datetime correctly in iOS/Safari using ionic2/angular2

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, safari, ionic2

Hi im facing a weird issue here im getting dynamic data in that im also getting the date and time and im displaying it in html using date pipe in chrome/android it is working good but when i check ios/Safari it is showing time difference

below is my json data im consuming

```
FromCurrentDate: "2018-01-05T00:00:00"

FromPreviousDate: "2018-01-04T00:00:00"


ToCurrentDate: "2018-01-05T14:00:53.137"

ToPreviousDate: "2018-01-04T14:00:53.137"
```

im displaying the date like this and
in chrome/android it is displaying like this[image]

[image]

in Ios/safari it is displaying like this
in the template  im using the code below

```
Currrent {{singleTable[0].FromCurrentDate|date: 'dd/MM/yyyy,h:mm:ss a'}} to {{singleTable[0].ToCurrentDate|date: 'dd/MM/yyyy,h:mm:ss a'}}
```

how can i solve this time difference issue?

Comment: Are you using Angular 5? Or a previous version?

Comment: @shadowlauch Angular 4

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if this causes the issue and sadly I can't check, because I don't have access to a Mac right now, but Angular 4 uses the intl API and that has caused some issues with Safari. Angular 5 switched away from the intl API for added constiency.

Comment: What is the difference? AM and PM?

Comment: @Duannxand it showing Am  and it is taking Darwin timezone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In ios/mac date filter doesn't work, so use moment.js for this.

I have tried lot of stuff but I was able to do best in moment.js

like: I created a pipe

```
<span>{{ActionDate | dateTimeFormatFilter : "MMM DD, YYYY"}}</span>

@Pipe({name: "dateTimeFormatFilter"})
@Injectable()
export class DateTimeFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(date: any, format: string): any {
        if (date) {
         return moment(date).format(format);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The issue you are facing is caused by the `Intl`api because `DatePipe` for Angular 2 Release is working fine only for FireFox and Chrome with custom format strings. 
it Doesn't work on Safari due to lack of Intl. so as a temporary work around is to include the Intl polyfill

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.en"></script>
```

**Solution 2** 
You can use the moment.js which can format your required date as follows

`moment(singleTable[0].FromCurrentDate).format("dd/MM/yyyy,h:mm:ss a")`

**Update 1**

In latest angular they have removed the Intl api , and for this you need to update to the angular 5 , [reference](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/18284)

**Update 2**
Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/h7LR3yI4TmDYhLuToN4Z) using  MomentJs in angular flavor, i added your date format but didn't tested in safari tested in chrome,

Comment: if i choose solution2  then on the html side can i use this moment.js

Comment: @Madpop yes you can , you can get the tutorials for those implementations also

Comment: but how can i give solution2 moment(singleTable[0].FromCurrentDate).format("dd/MM/yyyy,h:mm:ss a") in {{  }}

Comment: @Madpop as you are using the angular 2 , better try to use moment which supports modular format , ex : https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-moment

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same issue on safari on desktop and safari/chrome on iPhone. 
It works on safari or mostly all browsers when the date object is used as the value. ([DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe))

I resolved the same issue by adding a custom pipe to convert the date-time string into date object and then the date pipe works as expected.

**Component**

```
someDate1 = "2019-09-01 12:02:14";
someDate2 = "2019-09-01";
someDate3 = "2019-09-01 00:00:00";
```

**Template**

```
{{ someDate1 | toDateObj | date:'MM-dd-yyyy h:mm a' }}
```

Here is the `toDateObj` custom pipe I added.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'toDateObj'
})

export class ToDateObjPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any): any {
        if (value) {
            if (value.toString().indexOf(' ') === -1) {
                value = value + ' 00:00:00';
            }
            const temp = value.toString().replace(' ', 'T');
            return new Date(temp);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this works on Safari and on Chrome:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Pipe({
  name: 'customDate'
})

export class DatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {

      let dd = value.substr(8, 2);
      let MM = value.substr(5, 2);
      let yyyy = value.substr(0, 4);
      let date = `${dd}.${MM}.${yyyy}`;

      return `${date}`;
  }
}
```

I had a bug rendering views on Safari when chrome was ok. Later after debugging I found that pipe | date was a problem. So I made custom one. All answers up are great but importing moment library seems like a big file IMHO.
Just make this class export, make a module and declare it there(also export it) and use as example: {{_question.created_at  | toDateObj: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}}

Hope it helps someone